# Using apple push notification in my application in Detail?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

How can I use APN in my app?

I need to make my application using the APN. I need all the steps needed like is there another registration with apple for the certificates and how to make the push notification to all the devices that used my app downloaded from the store.

How should I implement the server side from which I will send the message?

I have already implemented this in my app:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
 registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | 
                                    UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | 
                                    UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

Comment: What problems did you have with the tutorials you read? It's hard to answer without knowing your specific problems with the existing documentation.

Comment: Your Server implementation totaly depends on the available technology (java, php, ruby, etc.). If you not even have a server yet, take a look at [UrbanAirship](http://urbanairship.com). Also take a look at the Apple Tutorials/Guides

Comment: my problem is i need the server to made by C# or by web (like a website on the server) but i dont know how to do it , the second thing is i want to know how to push this message to all the user who used the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this links. surely it will help you.

http://42spikes.com/post/Sending-Apple-Push-Notifications-from-a-C-Application.aspx or
    http://www.dotnetdrops.com/?p=308